# Java: Sort string list by a number contained within that string (descending)

Tags: java, sorting, substring

I have a .txt file of people's names and the score they achieve in a game, eg.

```
2 John
6 Matt
etc.
```

I'm trying to organise them in order of who has the highest score (number next to their name). I could use substring to get the integer and then `Collections.sort` but then I'm not sure how I would relate that back to the names.

If anyone has any smart ideas please help! I currently have it so all of the scores/names are read into an ArrayList, such as: `{2 John, 3 Matt}`

Comment: You could implement a class `PlayerScore` that 'contains' both a score and a player name and put instances of that class into your `ArrayList`. However, you will possibly run into another problem when it comes to sorting custom classes, but feel free to ask another question then.

Comment: I know it's probably an overkill, but I'd represent each name as an object i.e "2 john " would be a person object with an int to hold the number and string name to hold their name. C# structs would have been the best fit for this but since Java doesn't have structs it's obviously an overkill to implement this on such a small data but it would work. then you can just insert all the objects into your ArrayList and do a linear search for highest scorer and store that person object into another list but don't forget to remove the highest scorer from the arraylist containing unordered data.

Comment: Can you post the code of what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply implement a custom `Comparator<String>` and split on the first space (limit the split to `2`). I also assumed that ties should be ordered lexically (alphabetically). Like,

```
List<String> al = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("2 John", //
        "3 Matt", "3 Adam Smith"));
al.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        String[] a = o1.split("\\s+", 2); // <-- split on white space, limit 2.
        String[] b = o2.split("\\s+", 2);
        int r = Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(a[0]), //
                Integer.parseInt(b[0]));
        if (r != 0) {
            return -r;
        }
        return a[1].compareTo(b[1]);
    }
});
System.out.println(al);
```

Which outputs (as I think you wanted)

```
[3 Adam Smith, 3 Matt, 2 John]
```

Comment: Will try this later this afternoon, looks very promising thanks!